# Display Value in Epicor

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db, epicorerp

I am building an Epicor Configurator and I need to retrieve the Display Value of a Combo Box to a set it a a Part Description.  I am able to get the value fine but I want to be able to fetch the display value as well.  Your help is needed.

P.S. my combo box fetches its data from a BAQ.

Comment: I have tried txt1 = cmb1.DisplayValue  ....got an error

Comment: you should edit your question and post what you've tried and what error you get. Those information should be in the question not in comments as they cant be well formatted and are easily overseen.

Answer (score 0):

When I want the value in a text field, I've used

```
FieldName:SCREEN-VALUE
```

to get it's value.